# After installing node using nvm, the node command is not found

Tags: npm, nvm

[image]

1.I installed nvm to manage node versions(nvm -v:0.39.7)

2.And installed node by nvm

But, When I run nvm use 18 or 21 in terminal, follow this wrong:

nvm current:  none

node -v:  zsh: bus error  node -v

Thanks for your help

Tried reinstalling nvm and node

Comment: How did you install it? Also, can you check if your .zshrc has proper NVM_DIR and source nvm.sh statements?

Comment: If you just installed it, first open new terminal window and try again.

Comment: Try do do `echo $NVM_DIR` and see if it's defined

Comment: Execute: nvm install 18 or 21  install it.

Comment: @STerliakov Tried this, but the problem still exists.

Comment: @Lk77  ok, I got  :  /My user file directory/.nvm

Comment: @brc-dd   This is my zshrc code:

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"

source ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

you have to run . ~/.bash_profile or . ~/.bashrc to pick up the nvm command